# Can I say like this?

Tags: grammar

My friend is going come late to my home, can ask him like- isn't that would be late? If not, please correct this phrase

Comment: This would be more suited to our sister site [ell.se]. Please ensure to take their tour and read-up in their help center about how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest corrections to your question, as well:
"My friend is going to come late to my home. Can I ask him "Wouldn't that be late?".